# How to create a 3d earth that users can add pinpoints on?

Tags: swift, xcode, unity-game-engine, 3d, game-engine

What is the best software to create a 3d model of the earth, in which the user can rotate and zoom in. When the tap on a location, it creates a pinpoint to mark it. How would I go about this? I am new to 3d models, so any help is greatly appreciated. I want to place this model into an iOS app (Xcode).

Comment: Unfortunately your question is to broad. Here are steps you would probably take, try them, do your own research and come back with a specific questions if you are stuck and some point: 1. Create a 3D sphere 2. Add a texture of the Earth's surface 3. Implement an orbit and zoom Camera 4. Implement touch/tap recognition 5. Implement raycast to find hit point on the sphere 6. Implement pin setting at hitpoint ... For most of these I'm quite sure you'll find examples online ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are asking a lot and I think you should try doing it yourself first. If this seems hard, try searching for a tutorial.

Here is briefly what you should do and a link to a tutorial, post or thread to all of the steps:

**1. Create a model of earth and apply a texture on top of it.**

If you want to create your own model, I suggest you use **blender**, which is what I personally like the most of all 3D editing softwares currently available. [Blender Guru](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjEaoINr3zgEq0u2MzVgAaHEBt--xLB6U) has an awesome beginner course about blender.

If don't want to create your model all by yourself, [TurboSquid](https://www.turbosquid.com/Search/3D-Models/free/earth) has a ton of free models for you.

([Even nasa has made a 3D model of the earth!](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/resources/2393/earth-3d-model/))

**2. Implement a camera orbit feature**

This can be hard for beginners like you and me, but luckily [Emma Prats](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rDJOilo4Xrg&t=222s) has an amazing tutorial about it!

**3. Implement code to instantiate objects on top of earth**

[This](https://answers.unity.com/questions/119683/instantiate-object-at-mouse-position.html) thread should help.

***If you need help on something, make sure to post it here and we (the community) will try to help!***